# BuildpackCompileFailed - Issue pushing .NET application to Cloud Foundry

Tags: .net, cloud-foundry

I am trying to push a Cloud Foundry application but getting the following error:

```
   -----> Dotnet-Core Buildpack version 2.3.38
   -----> Supplying Dotnet Core
   -----> Installing libunwind 1.6.2
          Copy [/tmp/buildpacks/c92102b22f00696191613128d66113ab/dependencies/479f37cfbc77e7495a594d3017da0184/libunwind_1.6.2_linux_noarch_cflinuxfs3_02d17047.tgz]
          using the default SDK
   -----> Installing dotnet-sdk 3.1.416
          Copy [/tmp/buildpacks/c92102b22f00696191613128d66113ab/dependencies/01949c0fef686067a81b25d5f6307752/dotnet-sdk_3.1.416_linux_x64_any-stack_534be0cd.tar.xz]
 BuildpackCompileFailed - App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
```

Here is my manifest.yml file.

```
applications:
- name: WebApp2
memory: 512M
instances: 2
random-route: false
stack: windows2012R2
buildpack: hwc_buildpack
path: /WebApplication2/
```

I have tried the 'windows' and 'windows2012R2' stacks, however it appears to be trying to use something related to Linux. The application is based on .NET Framework 4.6.1.

I have pushed the same app from a different machine with no problems so it seems like an issue with the CF CLI or the computer configuration. One thing to note is that the API Endpoint version is different (machine that works is API Version 2.5, one that doesn't is API Version 3.99. Not sure how to change the API version.) Not sure what else to try, any suggestions welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Please remove the cfml tag. That question isn't cfml related.

Comment: Sorry, I it changed my "cf" tag to "cfml" automatically. Removed.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. My colleagues were using a different version of the CF CLI compared to my machine (they were using 7.4.0, I had 6.x.x). The syntax for manifest.yml is different for the different versions of the CF CLI.

CF CLI 6.5.3 actually provides a deprecation warning on the syntax we used but it still worked. Here is more info on the deprecation: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html#deprecated

Once they downloaded and used CF CLI 6.5.3, it pushed with no issues.